# How do I register multiple grunt-exec tasks?

Tags: node.js, shell, gruntjs, grunt-exec

I want to define a tree of shell commands in my `Gruntfile.js`, using `grunt-exec` to write shell commands.

I can do this for a single command, but I can't figure out the syntax for writing multiple sets of commands, and being able to call them one-by-one, or in groups.

Could someone please provide a fully fleshed out example `Gruntfile.js` with the following task structure?

```
test: `npm test`
lint:
  jshint: `jshint .`
  csslint: `csslint .`
```

I'm coming from the world of `make`, so I really want to shove this workflow into my Node.js projects, damn the Node community conventions.

I want `grunt` to default to `npm test`

I want `grunt lint` to perform both `jshint .` and `csslint .`

I want `grunt jshint` to perform only `jshint .`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A grunt multi-task supports multiple targets, but they can't be nested. But you can register tasks that run other tasks.

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
        exec: {
            test: "npm test",
            jshint: "jshint .",
            csslint: "csslint ."
        }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-exec");

  grunt.registerTask("default", ["exec:test"]);
  grunt.registerTask("test", ["exec:test"]);
  grunt.registerTask("lint", ["exec:jshint", "exec:csslint"]);
};
```

Note that there are already a lot of grunt tasks available, like [grunt-contrib-jshint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint), which make things much simpler.

Comment: The trick is to list each subtask out (grunt/grunt-exec does not seem to allow writing them nested). Then register them back into a hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Grunt lets you register tasks by name, and tasks of tasks. Easily done via arrays of string literal task names, e.g.:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['test']);
grunt.registerTask('lint', ['jshint', 'csslint']);
```

`jshint` should already be registered if you've defined it as `jshint` inside your `grunt.initConfig`. Keep in mind that, unusual for a node program, everything is highly synchronous. The tasks will run in the order you give them.

edit: in case you need it later, you can also registerTask a function instead of an array of task names. This is how you could go about writing a task that does async work, or if you have very strict ordering requirements that may use control flow logic. Try to stick with just registering based on task name if you can.